# How to have Kate spell check ignore run together words?

Tags: kde, programming, kate, spell-checking

I use Kate editor for scientific programming (Fortran, Python, matlab) and would like to leave spell check on, but have it automatically ignore words that have been run together to create a variable name, e.g., NewVariable or HugeMatrix.  There is an option in the spelling menu, but the spell check still highlights these words.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That is currently only possible by changing your highlighting xml files. Please read [how to write a syntax highlighting file](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/applications/kate/katehighlight-xml-format.html) and look for the `spellChecking` attribute. A possible solution for you is to add a RegExpr rule that matches these RunTogether words (something along the lines [a-zA-Z_]+[A-Z]\w*) and set an `itemData` (`attribute="..."`) where `spellChecking="false"`.